# Why eigenfunction cannot be identically zero in this question?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

[image: Applied Partial Differential Equations w - Haberman, Richard]

#### Below is part of the solution:

[image: A solution to this problem]

Comment: the boxed red section translates roughly to "It is intuitively obvious that" ...

Comment: This is the definition of an eigenvector in general.

Comment: Two related posts: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337410/an-eigenvector-is-a-non-zero-vector-such-that) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990016/can-the-zero-vector-be-an-eigenvector-for-a-matrix).

Answer (score 3):

Eigenvectors and eigenfunctions are precluded from being (identically) $0$ by definition.  Otherwise we would have, for any linear operator $L$ and any scalar value $r$,

$L(0) = 0 = r(0), \tag 1$

which says that *every* scalar is an eigenvalue of *every* operator.  Useless . . .

Answer (score 2):

An eigenvector $v$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$ for a linear operator $L$ is a nonzero vector such that the following holds:

$$Lv=\lambda v$$

That is to say that the operator $L$ acts on $v$ in the same way as multiplication by a scalar does.

Eigenfunctions are exactly the same as eigenvectors, the only difference being the name eigenfunction implies that we are talking specifically about a function space as opposed to an arbitrary vector space.  Function spaces *are* vector spaces, just specifically a vector space whose vectors are themselves functions.

We require that eigenvectors be nonzero because the zero vector trivially satisfies $L0=\lambda 0$ and this is incredibly uninteresting.  The interesting properties and theories surrounding eigenvectors and eigenvalues are those situations where there is a corresponding eigenspace (*a linear subspace of our vector space spanned entirely by eigenvectors for that corresponding eigenvalue*) of dimension strictly greater than zero.  As such, we opt to not call the zero vector an eigenvector as its existence alone as a solution to $Lv=\lambda v$ does not imply anything about the dimension of the eigenspace for $\lambda$.